# Provide API to get attendance for a meeting in Microsoft teams for organizers

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'd like to create an application for the MS teams meeting where the organizer of the meeting is able to get an email or able to download the Meeting attendance report , like the agenda of the meeting , Organizer name and details , Meeting participants names and their in time and out time(Active time)

In-order to proceed with the application , i need an API to fetch the Online Meeting details. The existing API is only applicable for Video Teleconference and requires admin access.

Existing 
links : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http 
and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Please provide with the API to get the online meeting details so that a meeting organizer can access it.

Comment: Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
You will get all the fields that you are looking for like in time and out time etc.

Comment: Can you please tell where can we fetch the id in GET /communications/calls/{id}/participants . I have tried keeping tid and oid but i am getting 500 Internal server error using graph explorer.

Comment: Please look at this document for get [attendance report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-analytics-and-reports/meeting-attendance-report).

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT
From where i can get {id} for this API
GET /communications/calls/{id}/participants

Comment: Hi Yashwanth, did you get answer to this? where to get id to call this API?